# Kubernetes pod having containers of different privileges

Tags: kubernetes

Can a pod have two containers of different privilege level? For example Container 'A' is a regular container and Container 'B' is a privileged container that can alter the network stack. Both containers will be packaged in a single pod. Now if the pod's privileged parameter is set true, would it mean that both of the containers are now privileged? or otherwise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pod-level security context applies to all containers in the pod, but the per-container security context can override the settings for the individual container [[1]](https://github.com/kubernetes/community/blob/master/contributors/design-proposals/pod-security-context.md).

I'd suggest setting the pod-level default as secure (with minimal privilege) as possible, and only override the privilege setting for the containers that truly need it.

Comment: Thanks, is it also possible that a user Alice can only access one of the non privileged containers but not the privileged one? And a user Bob can access all both privileged and others if it gets access to the pod?